# Smooth vector field on manifold and coordinate systems

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm trying to solve the following problem from the book "Semi-Riemannian Geometry" by Barrett O'Neill (first edition):

> A vector field $V$ on M is smooth if for sufficiently many coordinate system $\xi$ to cover M the functions $Vx^i$ are smooth

My attempt:

Let A be a complete atlas on M, i.e., any $\xi \in A$ intersects all $\eta \in A$. As $\xi$ is a homeomorphism from $U \subset M \rightarrow R$, we have that $\xi$ and $\xi^{-1}$ are continuous. Then,  if $\xi=(x^1,...,x^i)$, $x^i$ must be continuous.
Let $\partial_i$ be a vector field on U and $p \in U$. So $\partial_i x^i=\frac{\partial_i x^i}{\partial_i x_i}$ which is smooth.

Comment: Are you sure you've transcribed that correctly? Imagine a vector field on $S^1$, non-smooth at $\theta = \pi$ (e.g., $V(\theta) = \theta^3$, where $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$). Now $n = 3$ coord charts suffice to cover $S^1$. So pick $\theta \mapsto \sin \theta$ on the intervals $(-b, b)$ for $b = \pi, \pi/2, \pi/4$. Those give $n=3$ coordinate systems on which $Vx_i$ is smooth, but $V$ is not globally smooth. I think you need to say $V$ is smooth if there's a a covering of $M$ by charts $x_i, i \in I$ such that $Vx_i$ is smooth for each $i$. A mere count is not sufficient!

Comment: Yes, I've just reviewed the question on the book. I discussed this problem with a math PhD yesterday and she had problems understanding it too. Should I assume the question is ill formed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $V$ can be locally written as $V=a_1X_i+...+a_nX_n$, where $a_i’s$ are (not necessarily smooth) maps on the manifold and $X_i$ is the local vector field corresponding to the $i$th coordinate of the local chart. Since $V(x_i)$ is smooth for all $i$ by hypothesis, each $a_i$ which is equal to $V(x_i)$ is smooth. Hence $V$ is smooth.